# Nested ResourceT scopes within a conduit Sink

Tags: haskell, conduit

Is there a way to scope `runResourceT` to the lifetime of a single `Sink`?

I'm trying to build a `Sink` that wraps a potentially infinite number of `Sinks`. This works fine with threads but I'm trying to do it without threads. It seems like it should be possible. I've hit a road block due to the scoping of `runResourceT`: I get either too coarsely grained (but functional) or much too finely grained (totally broken) resource management.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC8 (pack)
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as Cb
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as Cl
import System.FilePath ((<.>))

test :: IO ()
test =
  runResourceT
      $ Cl.sourceList (fmap (BC8.pack . show) [(1 :: Int)..1000])
     $$ rotateResourceHog "/tmp/foo"

-- |
-- files are allocated on demand but handles are released at the same time
rotateResourceHog
  :: MonadResource m
  => FilePath -> Sink ByteString m ()
rotateResourceHog filePath = step 0 where
  step i = do
    x <- Cl.peek
    case x of
      Just _  -> do
        chunkWriter $ filePath <.> show (i :: Integer)
        -- loop
        step $ i+1

      Nothing -> return ()

-- |
-- files are allocated on demand but handles are released immediately
rotateUsingClosedHandles
  :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadResource m)
  => FilePath -> Sink ByteString m ()
rotateUsingClosedHandles filePath = step 0 where
  step i = do
    x <- Cl.peek
    case x of
      Just _  -> do
        transPipe runResourceT . chunkWriter $ filePath <.> show (i :: Integer)
        -- loop
        step $ i+1

      Nothing -> return ()

chunkWriter
  :: MonadResource m
  => FilePath -> Sink ByteString m ()
chunkWriter filePath = do
  _ <- lift $ allocate (putStrLn "alloc") (\ _ -> putStrLn "free")

  -- the actual conduit chain is more complicated
  Cl.isolate 100 =$= Cb.sinkFile filePath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResourceT` is only intended to clean up resources in exceptional cases. It is not intended to provide *prompt* finalization, only *guaranteed* finalization. For promptness, `conduit` provides its own facilities for handling cleanup. In your case, you're looking for both: you want cleanup to happen as early as possible, and to occur even in the case of an exception being thrown. For this, you should use `bracketP`. For example:

```
chunkWriter
  :: MonadResource m
  => FilePath -> Sink ByteString m ()
chunkWriter filePath = bracketP
    (putStrLn "alloc")
    (\() -> putStrLn "free")
    (\() -> Cl.isolate 100 =$= Cb.sinkFile filePath)
```

This results in the desired interleaving of alloc and free outputs.

Comment: What I need is prompt cleanup of the sink handle (and other state from gzip/lzma conduits), that might not have been clear in the question. I was using `allocate` to track this. `bracketP` doesn't seem to help here since the resources are allocated within the sink itself.

Comment: `sinkFile` should release the handle as soon as no more input is available. Do you have evidence that this isn't happening? If so, it's a bug, and needs to be fixed.

Comment: No, there is various other code laying about that is relying on `ResourceT` for cleanup and it seems like this is a problem.